# auto-mounting your extra drive in linux and facing "fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/my-name/folder/sub-folder/sub-folder1'"

Tags: linux, git, filesystems, chown

I moved to Linux from Windows. And **auto-mounted my extra drive[hdd] to a directory I created in Home.**

After hitting git status or any git command I get this message:
`fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at /home/my-name/folder/sub-folder/sub-folder1`
As suggested in other Stackoverflow questions with this error, I thought this is an ownership issue and would fix with something like the equivalent of `TAKEOWN` command in Windows. So, I run `chown -R <username> <repo-dir>` and `chown -R <username:groupname> <repo-dir>` but nothing seems to work.

Should I just go with `git config --global --add safe.directory /home/my-name/folder/sub-folder/sub-folder1`.
I am hesitant to go with this because I don't understand why it is fatal in the first place and whether making it safe would have some implications?

I am on PopOS 22.04 and git 2.42.0

Comment: Try running `ls -la /home/my-name/folder/sub-folder/sub-folder1` and check the owner/group and permissions on that directory.

Comment: @dan1st it shows "root" owner and "root" group. after running `id` command my username is "avi" and group is "avi"

Comment: Then you should probably change both the owner and the group of that directory to `avi`. When entering `chown -R avi:avi /home/my-name/folder/sub-folder/sub-folder1` or `sudo chown -R avi:avi /home/my-name/folder/sub-folder/sub-folder1`, do you get any output? What number is shown when entering `echo $?` right after the `chown` command?

Comment: I got 0. And after using `sudo chown -R` nothing seems to happen. root:root is not changed @dan1st

Comment: This means the `chown` command was successful. Make sure you really used the correct directory and that you have the same permissions in subdirectory-

Comment: yes. I am using the current directory, I'm sure of it. I also check when I make any folder or file, I get root:root as my username and group. So, the directory is okay. It's the fact that I moved from Windows to Linux is the issue. Because git repos I made on Linux don't throw that error but the repos I already had in my ssd are all throwing the same error

Comment: Which file system are you on, and what mount options is it mounted with? This looks like a filesystem problem, not a git problem.

Comment: @root I have solved it. I added `uid=1000` in my disks utility for the extra hdd that I mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.
The problem was I was enabling auto-mounting on my extra drive[hdd] and mounting it to a folder at Home. When doing this, my OS was changing the ownership (user and group) to `root`.
You need to change the ownership back to YOUR user and group. To know your user and group name, open terminal and type `id` and enter. You will something like this:
[image]
Note the ids for your user(uid) and groups(gid). In my case `uid=1000` and `gid=1000`, "avi" is the user name here.

Now, open "Disks" utility(also known as gnome-disks) for Gnome users. (If you're in KDE, look for "partitionmanager")
Select your extra drive -> settings -> edit mount options.
[image]

Then add `,uid=1000,gid=1000` like shown
[image]

Hopefully, this will fix your problem if your issue is similar to mine.